# Probability with qualifications and gender

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

```
 Qualification  Female Male
  Degree        5       1
  None          5       4
  School        8      12
  Vocation      8       7
```

I've been going through some previous exam questions and came across this one:

With this set of data, how would you find the probability that a randomly selected person is male and has a degree or vocation quaification?

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way would be to observe that:

1. There are $7$ persons that are males *and* have vocation qualification and
2. There is $1$ person that is male *and* has a degree qualification, which makes a total of $$7+1=8$$ persons that match the specified criteria,
3. Out of a total of $50$ persons. Therefore the required probability is equal to $$\frac{7+1}{50}=\frac{8}{50}=0.16 \qquad \text{ or }\,\, 16\%$$
   since if we select a person in random, each person has *equal probability* to be selected.